# Jasmine unit tests: $compile produces comment out of ng-repeat

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, comments, jasmine, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why the line

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
dump($compile('<ul><li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]">{{item}}</li></ul>')(scope));
```

results in:

```
'<ul class="ng-scope"><!-- ngRepeat: item in [1,3,5,7,9] --></ul>'
```

I would like to see `<li>` items rather than comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you're missing the [`digest`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest) method to go all the way

```js
var e = $compile('<div><ul><li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]">{{item}}</li></ul></div>')(scope);
scope.$digest();
console.log(e.html());
```

This is the output I get now:

```html
Safari 537.21 (Linux) LOG: '
<ul><!-- ngRepeat: item in [1,3,5,7,9] -->
<li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">1</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">3</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">5</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">7</li>
<li ng-repeat="item in [1,3,5,7,9]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">9</li>
</ul>'
```

Comment: Thank you, it did the job! There is written that `$apply()` is more preferable; I tried it and it has worked too!

Comment: apply didnt work for me incase of a variable which is set asynchronously.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110497/angularjs-testing-directive-html-not-re-rendered-after-promise-completion